# DatagramSocket not throwing SocketTimeout - Java

Tags: java, sockets, datagram

My datagram socket is not throwing a SocketTimeout despite it being set and I'm not sure how to resolve this. The code is as follows. The thing is, if it doesn't receive any messages along this socket connection, it will timeout on the first run through. However, it successfully receives a message a couple of times, it won't timeout later on when a .receive is called.

```
DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(serverSyncPort);
serverSocket.setSoTimeout(200);

while(true)
{
        receiveData = new byte[1024];
        receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData,receiveData.length);
        try
        {
            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
        }
        catch(SocketTimeoutException e) {}
}
```

Comment: With that exception handling, how could you possibly tell?

Comment: That was just the portion of code. I had it output within the catch block to the console

Comment: I know this is really old but did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

From the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29)

> If the timeout expires, a java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised, though the DatagramSocket is 
>   still valid. **The option must be enabled prior to entering the blocking operation to have effect.** 
>   The timeout must be > 0. A timeout of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout.

Check whether the timeout is enabled properly or not as highlighted in above quote.

Also,  later check the value for [`getSoTimeout()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#getSoTimeout), to verify what it is.

Comment: I've checked it before and after the receive each time and it's still at 200, yet does not timeout when it goes through the loop and does not receive anything ...

Answer (score 0):

A call to receive() for this DatagramSocket will block for only setsockettimeout amount of time. If the timeout expires, a java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised, though the DatagramSocket is still valid. Here 200 milisecond is set as time out and it should work.

Which environment you are trying on ? It's possible this is the expected behaviour on Windows, as SocketException is coming fine on solaris / Linux env.

Comment: setSoTimeout() works on all Java platforms that I am aware of. Otherwise it wouldn't be there.